# Which are the positive integers $ r $ such that $\mathbb{Z}^{r} $ can be endowed with a structure of UFD?

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, prime-numbers

The ring of integers  $ \mathbb{Z} $ is a unique factorization domain. Similarly, the ring  $ \mathbb{Z}[i] $ of Gaussian integers, which can be viewed as  $ \mathbb{Z}^{2} $, is a UFD.

So my question is : which are the positive integers  $ r $ such that  $ \mathbb{Z}^{r} $ can be endowed with the structure of UFD ?

Motivation : trying to prove that if  $ \mathbb{Z}^{m} $ can't be endowed with a structure of a UFD, then the maximal prime gap around  $ x $ is a little oh of the average prime gap around  $ x$ to the power  $ m $ , hence  $ \max_{n\le\pi(x)}p_{n+1}-p_{n}=o(\log^{m}x) $ . This would be a first step towards Cramer's conjecture.

Comment: Do you know any examples of such integers?

Comment: For $K$ a number field of degree $n$, $\mathcal{O}_K$ is always finite free of rank $n$, so equivalently you want to know which degrees $n$ have the property that there is a number field of that degree with class number $1$. This is probably wide open but presumably something is known about it; Wikipedia has a very partial list of number fields with class number $1$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_number_fields_with_class_number_one

Comment: To expand on Qiaochu's comment: conversely, if $R$ is a UFD whose additive group is $\mathbb{Z}^r$, then the field of fractions of $R$ is a number field of degree $r$ and $R$ is its ring of integers.

Comment: Does "can be viewed as $\Bbb Z^r$" means that's the additive group of the ring, or something more?

Comment: I don't think number fields whose integers are UFD has anything to do with prime gaps.

Comment: @reuns : my idea is that primes are archetypal building blocks of UFDs, since those rings fulfill an analogue of the fundamental theorem of arithmetics. So their distribution, hence maximal prime gaps, should be a reformulation of this phenomenon.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque : I want to know if one can consider r-uplets of integers and define two composition laws + and x that turn the consider set of r-uplets into a UFD.

Comment: @SylvainJulien Obviously you can do it if you are allowed to redefine the addition, since then you just have a countable set. I assumed you meant to fix the usual addition.

Comment: You might find of interest [Abstract Analytic Number Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_analytic_number_theory), e.g. see the Dover textbook with that title by Knopfmacher. Peruse the (readable) introduction to see if that is the flavor of results that you seek.

Comment: My question originates from extending the notion of prime gap from a 1-dimensional setting, as points in a lattice. Between  $ p_n $ and  $ p_{n+1} $ there are  $g_{n}= p_{n+1}-p_{n} $ in an "elementary cell", i.e. containing 1 prime (both  $ p_{n} $ and  $ p_{n+1} $ count for 1/2 as each belong to 2 adjacent such cells). Tbc

Comment: In the complex plane such an elementary cell is formed by a square whose vertices have coordinates  $ (p_{n},p_{n}) $,  $ (p_{n},p_{n+1}) $,  $(p_{n+1}, p_{n}) $,  $ p_{n+1},p_{n+1}) $ and contains  $ g_{n}^2 $ points. My idea is that  $ g_n\le(1+o(1))\log^{d} x $ with  $ d $ the maximal dimension of a lattice built from a UFD canonically isomorphic to  $ \mathbb{Z}^{r} $ for some integer  $ r $ .

Comment: It seems you want to factorize the elements of the non-integral ring $\mathbb{Z}^r$ (the ring with pointwise multiplication) in term of the usual primes numbers, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: No. I want to extend the multiplication in Z to Z^r so that the induced multiplication reduces to the usual one when the last r-1 components vanish. Think of multiplication of complex numbers that reduce to multiplication of reals when imaginary parts vanish. I want to know if the maximal 1-dimensional volume of an 1D elementary cell is at most the d-dimensional volume of the corresponding elementary cell in d dimensions.